# redirect old url to new one in open cart

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, opencart

I looking for some help to solve this issue. i'm using open cart and made a product long time ago, of course i'm used SEO url for this product.

> **Ex.** example.com/myproduct

but now i decided to change this url:

> **Ex.** example.com/newproduct

it's now working and up in new url but google indexed that old url and i trying to redirect that old url to new one but no success.

first i tried `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteRule ^myproduct$ https://example.com/newproduct [R=301,L]
```

it's not working, then write with old method, 301 redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /myproduct https://example.com/newproduct
```

it's look like redirected but there is a problem, when i run that old url it redirect to new url like this:

> example.com/newproduct?*route*=myproduct

it show 404 page not found. but if i using fake url for example:

```
Redirect 301 /oldtest https://example.com/newtest
```

it's working fine! i'm  wondering why it's not working!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this is because OpenCart is handling it and interfering with what you are doing. Use your first idea:

```
RewriteRule ^myproduct$ https://example.com/newproduct [R=301,L]
```

But make sure it is at the top of your .htaccess file before anything else from OpenCart. Make sure it has `RewriteEngine On` before it.

Comment: It is OpenCart, see [this thread for a solution](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=21971) or find the old product URL listed within OpenCart database and remove it so you can use the above.